# Check for entering numbers only

Tags: javascript, html

I have a problem
I make a check when you enter upper or lower case letters in the text input to warn that letters cannot be entered but only numbers.
how to make i only enter numbers in the input?

```
<input type="text" id="texter">
<button onclick="checker()">
START
</button>


checker = () =>{
 var texter = document.getElementById('texter').value;
 if(texter.search(/[a-z]/)){
     alert("letters");
   return false;
 }
 else if(texter.search(/[A-Z]/)){
    alert("letters big");
  return false;
 }
 else{
        return true;
 }
}
```

Comment: Whitelist numbers instead of blacklisting everything else. Also you are looking for `oninput` instead of `onclick`.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/number

Comment: FYI, you can use `<input type="number">` for better user experience

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the best user experience, using `type="number"` on your input is the best bet.

```html
<input type="number" />
```

If you need it to be a "text" type, one thing you can do is strip any non-numeric character from the string and set the value of the textbox to this string:

```js
const textbox = document.querySelector('#texter');

textbox.onkeyup = event => {
  const stripped = event.target.value.replace(/\D/g,'');
  textbox.value = stripped;
}
```

```html
<input id="texter" />
```

Comment: can you explain to me exactly what this is doing @Nick

Comment: Sure, the first line is taking the `value` of our textbox and using a regular expression in `replace` to replace any non-numbers with empty strings. The second line simply assigns the textbox value to that new `stripped` value.

Answer (score 0):

sorry but why don't just use number type of the input

```
<input type='number'id='texter' />
```

here you don't need to check for number this input just accept numbers